# Kinetic JS (Dragging a ball along with mouse pointer)

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, kineticjs

I tried moving a ball object along with the mouse pointer by dragging set true and setting it as an object.

Here's my javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = [];
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
        listening: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
        listening: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        radius: 5,
        fill: 'cyan',
        stroke: 'black',
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(circle);
    stage.add(layer);
    stage.getContent().addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        var mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
        var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
            node: circle,
            x: mousePos.x,
            y: mousePos.y,
            duration: 0.001,
            easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut
        });
        tween.play();
        layer.draw();
    });
    stage.getContent().addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
        var mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
        var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
            node: circle,
            x: mousePos.x,
            y: mousePos.y,
            duration: 0.0001,
            easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut
        });
        tween.play();
        layer.batchDraw();
    });
});
```

Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Collision Detection</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style=" background:#000; margin:auto; float:left;"></div>
        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/kinetic-v5.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/main_kinetic.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I got the output ,but its lagging.
I wonder if its the same for u guys?
Can u suggest an alternative for this.. or resolve this lag?

EDIT :http://jsfiddle.net/BVeTH/
This is my JSfiddle.
THere aint much lagging in the fiddle,but when i try to work it in my system,it does lag a lot.
Any idea?

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle, if you want us to run the code and test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mousemove events are fired 20-30 times per second, so don't play tweens in your mousemove handler.

That's the source of your lagging.

Luckily, you don't need tweening to get your circle to move with the mouse.

Just do this:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4Ubf6/

```
// move the circle with the mouse

stage.getContent().addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
    circle.setPosition(stage.getPointerPosition());
    layer.draw();
});
```

And, you can remove the mouseover event listener completely  --  mousemove will do the whole job by itself.

Comment: I removed that tween play() ,still the same result.
Plus check my edit also.

Comment: You don't need tweening at all to get the circle to move with the mouse.  Remove all tweening and instead use circle.setPosition.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanx,I just found out the problem..
The program works smoothly if i just double click the index file.
But it lags via localhost.
Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Okie,its not the localhost.
It works fine on chrome,but not on firefox..
am working on firefox 26.0(Mozilla firefox for ubuntu canonical 1.0)
Operating system: Ubuntu 32bit

Comment: Mozilla is working through several canvas+drag related bugs that appear on Linux boxes.  Since you've removed the tween from inside mousemove I must unhappily report that you must wait for the Mozilla+Linux bug to be fixed. :-(  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=561361

Comment: Thank you MarkE.
Glad that to know its not my fault,and a bug :)
Hope they fix it soon.